# How to convert date to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date column in a pandas dataframe in the format mm/dd/yyyy and I would like to convert it to an integer in the format yyyymmdd. Is this possible using datetime?

Answer (score 2):

You can either mangle the strings and cast to integer directly (more efficient) or convert to datetime, format to string and cast to integer (maybe more convenient / readable).

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
# dummy data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['10/11/2012', '11/12/2013']}) # mm/dd/yyyy
# working with strings...
tmp = df['date'].str.split('/')
df['date_int'] = (tmp.str[2]+tmp.str[0]+tmp.str[1]).astype(int)
# working with datetime...
df['date_int'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
```

output in both cases:

```
0    20121011
1    20131112
Name: date_int, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum year * 10000 + month * 100 + day:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-05')})
df['dt_int'] = df['dt'].dt.year * 10000 + df['dt'].dt.month * 100 + df['dt'].dt.day

df
```

Output:

```
          dt    dt_int
0 2021-01-01  20210101
1 2021-01-02  20210102
2 2021-01-03  20210103
3 2021-01-04  20210104
4 2021-01-05  20210105
```

---

**Update**

If column values are strings with a known format `mm/dd/yyyy`, you can concatenate the substrings and convert to integer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': ['10/11/2012', '11/12/2013']})
df['dt_int'] = (
    df['dt'].str[6:] +
    df['dt'].str[0:2] +
    df['dt'].str[3:5]).astype(int)
```

This can save some time compared to the version with `split`:

```
%%time
df['dt_int'] = (
    df['dt'].str[6:] +
    df['dt'].str[3:5] +
    df['dt'].str[0:2]).astype(int)

CPU times: user 7.08 ms, sys: 646 µs, total: 7.72 ms
Wall time: 6.95 ms
```

```
%%time
tmp = df['dt'].str.split('/')
df['dt_int'] = (tmp.str[2]+tmp.str[0]+tmp.str[1]).astype(int)

CPU times: user 16.5 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 16.5 ms
Wall time: 15.5 ms
```

Comment: The dates aren't datetime objects, they're just strings.

Comment: what if someone supplies non-zero-padded day/month? efficiency comes at the cost of increased specificity ^^

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes, that's why I explicitly said *if column values are strings with a known format mm/dd/yyyy* (which is how it's specified in the question). By definition `mm` is a two-digit month, `dd` is a two-digit day of the month. If you can be more efficient, probably no reason not to (readability aside, but here it's more or less the same I would say)

Comment: Should be `year * 10000`, not `year * 1000` :)